# Simulating MySQL's ORDER BY FIELD() in Postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Just trying out PostgreSQL for the first time, coming from MySQL.  In our Rails application we have a couple of locations with SQL like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `currency_codes` ORDER BY FIELD(code, 'GBP', 'EUR', 'BBD', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'USD') DESC, name ASC
```

It didn't take long to discover that this is not supported/allowed in PostgreSQL.

Does anyone know how to simulate this behaviour in PostgreSQL or do we have to pull sorting out into the code?

Comment: It might be useful to explain what you want to achieve. As hard to imagine as it is - not everybody knows MySQL :)

Comment: Great point depesz!  Basically a custom sort order is what we are after.  The FIELD function allows you to create custom set to do your sorting with.

Comment: Now in Rails you may consider `#in_order_of` https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42061

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Ah, gahooa was so close:

```
SELECT * FROM currency_codes
  ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN code='USD' THEN 1
    WHEN code='CAD' THEN 2
    WHEN code='AUD' THEN 3
    WHEN code='BBD' THEN 4
    WHEN code='EUR' THEN 5
    WHEN code='GBP' THEN 6
    ELSE 7
  END,name;
```

Comment: This method does not work when you are using DISTINCT. Any other ideas for this scenario?

Comment: I'm not sure why this works, but I figured out an alternative. If you want results in order by j, a, k, e, then you `order by id=e, id=k, id=a, id=j`.

Comment: Shouldn't the ELSE be 0? That's what FIELD returns for no match.

Comment: @Corey Perhaps you can wrap results from your DISTINCT with another SELECT which implements the above?

Answer (score 32):

sort in mysql:

```
> ids = [11,31,29]
=> [11, 31, 29]
> User.where(id: ids).order("field(id, #{ids.join(',')})")
```

in postgres:

```
def self.order_by_ids(ids)
  order_by = ["CASE"]
  ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
    order_by << "WHEN id='#{id}' THEN #{index}"
  end
  order_by << "END"
  order(order_by.join(" "))
end

User.where(id: [3,2,1]).order_by_ids([3,2,1]).map(&:id) 
#=> [3,2,1]
```

Comment: Gold. Railsy way.

Comment: `order_by_ids` won't work on Rails 6.1, it will raise `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference` error https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/UnknownAttributeReference.html

Comment: For Rails 6.1 and above, you need to use Arel instead. In case you are looking for a solution for Rails 6.1, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66517571/7313509

Comment: Anyone able to provide a Laravel version?

Answer (score 15):

**Update**, fleshing out terrific suggestion by @Tometzky.

This ought to give you a MySQL `FIELD()`-alike function under pg 8.4:

```
-- SELECT FIELD(varnames, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz')
CREATE FUNCTION field(anyelement, VARIADIC anyarray) RETURNS numeric AS $$
  SELECT
    COALESCE(
     ( SELECT i FROM generate_subscripts($2, 1) gs(i)
       WHERE $2[i] = $1 ),
     0);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE
```

*Mea culpa*, but I cannot verify the above on 8.4 right now; however, I can work backwards to a "morally" equivalent version that works on the 8.1 instance in front of me:

```
-- SELECT FIELD(varname, ARRAY['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION field(anyelement, anyarray) RETURNS numeric AS $$
  SELECT
    COALESCE((SELECT i
              FROM generate_series(1, array_upper($2, 1)) gs(i)
              WHERE $2[i] = $1),
             0);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE
```

More awkwardly, you still can portably use a (possibly derived) table of currency code rankings, like so:

```
pg=> select cc.* from currency_codes cc
     left join
       (select 'GBP' as code, 0 as rank union all
        select 'EUR', 1 union all
        select 'BBD', 2 union all
        select 'AUD', 3 union all
        select 'CAD', 4 union all
        select 'USD', 5) cc_weights
     on cc.code = cc_weights.code
     order by rank desc, name asc;
 code |           name
------+---------------------------
 USD  | USA bits
 CAD  | Canadian maple tokens
 AUD  | Australian diwallarangoos
 BBD  | Barbadian tridents
 EUR  | Euro chits
 GBP  | British haypennies
(6 rows)
```

Comment: The first one works great on postgres 11, after changing the return type to 'integer'. Very handy for ordering by 'foreign' data.

Answer (score 13):

This is I think the simplest way:

```
create temporary table test (id serial, field text);
insert into test(field) values
  ('GBP'), ('EUR'), ('BBD'), ('AUD'), ('CAD'), ('USD'),
  ('GBP'), ('EUR'), ('BBD'), ('AUD'), ('CAD'), ('USD');
select * from test
order by field!='GBP', field!='EUR', field!='BBD',
  field!='AUD', field!='CAD', field!='USD';
 id | field 
----+-------
  1 | GBP
  7 | GBP
  2 | EUR
  8 | EUR
  3 | BBD
  9 | BBD
  4 | AUD
 10 | AUD
  5 | CAD
 11 | CAD
  6 | USD
 12 | USD
(12 rows)
```

In PostgreSQL 8.4 you can also use a [function with variable number of arguments](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS) (variadic function) to port `field` function.

Comment: +1 for order-by-bang, and for `VARIADIC` suggestion, which I'll try to implement.

Answer (score 12):

```sql
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('foo'), ('bar'), ('baz'), ('egg'), ('lol')) t1(name)
ORDER BY ARRAY_POSITION(ARRAY['foo', 'baz', 'egg', 'bar'], name)
```

How about this? Above one fetches as below:

```
foo
baz
egg
bar
lol
```

As you already get it, if an element isn't in the array then it goes to the back. Note that you can also use the same technique if you need an `IN` operator with a custom sort order:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE id IN (17, 5, 11)
ORDER BY ARRAY_POSITION(ARRAY[17, 5, 11], id);
```

Comment: [42883] ERROR: function array_position(text[], uuid) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 240

Comment: @AkimKelar yes, as the hint says, you need to add explicit type cast to the latter argument in ARRAY_POSITION.

Comment: I know this is a Rails question but for anyone using **Django**, [there is an elegant way to implement this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55650521/1164966).

Answer (score 5):

[ilgam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26777669/7313509) won't work since Rails 6.1, an `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference` error will be raised: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/UnknownAttributeReference.html

The recommended way is to use Arel instead of raw SQL.

In addition to [ilgam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26777669/7313509), here is the solution for Rails 6.1:

```
def self.order_by_ids(ids)
  t = User.arel_table
  condition = Arel::Nodes::Case.new(t[:id])
  ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
    condition.when(id).then(index)
  end
  order(condition)
end
```

Comment: Perfect. Just added "return self unless ids.any?" at beginning

Comment: Actually "return all unless ids.any?" (all preserve the scope chaining)

Answer (score 4):

Actually the version for postgres 8.1 as another advantage.

When calling a postgres function you cannot pass more than 100 parameters to it, so your ordering can be done at maximum on 99 elements.

Using the function using an array as second argument instead of having a variadic argument just remove this limit.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this...

```
SELECT 
   ..., code
FROM 
   tablename
ORDER BY 
   CASE 
      WHEN code='GBP' THEN 1
      WHEN code='EUR' THEN 2
      WHEN code='BBD' THEN 3
      ELSE 4
   END
```

But why are you hardcoding these into the query -- wouldn't a supporting table be more appropriate?

--

**Edit: flipped it around as per comments**

Comment: @gahooa, I think you've the sense of "code" reversed -- the code is the three alpha abbreviation, which the OP desires to sort in a non-alpha fashion.

Comment: I wish I could take credit for why the SQL is the way it is, we are working on a refactor, but I admit I am looking for the quick fix right now

Answer (score 3):

For folks coming here later, Rails 7 added `in_order_of`, so you can do:

```rb
CurrencyCode.in_order_of(:code, 'GBP', 'EUR', 'BBD', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'USD')
```

See also: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-in_order_of

Comment: Worked like a charm! Needs more upvotes. And to confirm, you can chain this with other methods. I just used it like this:

`query.reorder(nil).in_order_of(:current_status, ordered_statuses).order(starts_on: :asc)`

Answer (score 2):

Just define the `FIELD` function and use it. It's easy enough to implement. The following should work in 8.4, as it has `unnest` and window functions like `row_number`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION field(text, VARIADIC text[]) RETURNS bigint AS $$
SELECT n FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER () AS n, x FROM unnest($2) x
) numbered WHERE numbered.x = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE 'SQL' IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

You can also define another copy with the signature:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION field(anyelement, VARIADIC anyarray) RETURNS bigint AS $$
```

and the same body if you want to support `field()` for any data type.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, but when I try to create the function, pgadmin says - "return type mismatch in function declared to return bigint, Function's final statement must be select/insert" ideas?

Comment: @chrismarx Pg version? `Select version()`

Comment: also unnest doesn't seem to be a registered function, "PostgreSQL 9.3.4 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn), 64-bit"

Comment: That sounds pretty borked. `unnest` has been around since 8.4... Show `\df unnest` please

Answer (score 1):

If you'll run this often, add a new column and a pre-insert/update trigger. Then you set the value in the new column based on this trigger and order by this field. You can even add an index on this field.

Comment: Triggers are bad, mmkay? Avoid if at all possible!

Comment: @WillSheppard That is wrong. They can't be used brainlessly and often, but you simply can't say "Triggers are bad"

Answer (score 1):

Create a migration with this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION field(anyelement, VARIADIC anyarray) RETURNS bigint AS $$
  SELECT n FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER () AS n, x FROM unnest($2) x)
      numbered WHERE numbered.x = $1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Then just do this

```
sequence = [2,4,1,5]
Model.order("field(id,#{sequence.join(',')})")
```

voila!

Answer (score 0):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29039262/1103543), I just released a gem ([order_as_specified](https://github.com/panorama-ed/order_as_specified)) that allows you to do native SQL ordering like this:

```
CurrencyCode.order_as_specified(code: ['GBP', 'EUR', 'BBD', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'USD'])
```

It returns an ActiveRecord relation, and thus can be chained with other methods, and it's worked with every RDBMS I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to do this ordering using the array `unnest` together `WITH ORDINALITY` functionality:

```sql
--- Table and data setup ...
CREATE TABLE currency_codes (
     code text null,
     name text
);
INSERT INTO currency_codes
  (code)
VALUES
  ('USD'), ('BBD'), ('GBP'), ('EUR'), ('AUD'), ('CAD'), ('AUD'), ('AUD');

-- ...and the Query
SELECT
  c.*
FROM
  currency_codes c
JOIN
  unnest('{"GBP", "EUR", "BBD", "AUD", "CAD", "USD"}'::text[])
  WITH ORDINALITY t(code, ord)
  USING (code)
ORDER BY t.ord DESC, c.name ASC;
```