# django - order query set by postgres function

Tags: django

My initial question was here and was related to the postgres backend. [Postgres subquery, ordering by subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408965/postgres-subquery-ordering-by-subquery)

Now my problem has moved onwards to the Django ORM layer. I essentially want to order a query by a postgres function ('idx', taken from the above stackoverflow work)

I've gone through trying to use model.objects.extra(order_by ) or simply order_by but I believe both of these need the order_by parameter to be an attribute or a field known to Django.

I'm trying to think how to solve this without having to revert to using an entirely raw SQL query through a model manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `extra` to add the function result to your query and then order by it. Something like:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select={'idx': 'idx(foo, bar)'}, order_by=['idx'])
```

Comment: that's a brilliant answer. I wish I could give you more than a plus