# PostgreSQL ORDER BY values in IN() clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, sql-in

Ok, there are some answers out there on how to do this. But all of the answers are assuming that the query is selecting all. If you have a distinct select, the methods no longer work.

See here for that method: [Simulating MySQL's ORDER BY FIELD() in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql)

Basically I have

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM items 
WHERE id IN (5,2,9) 
ORDER BY
 CASE id
  WHEN 5 THEN 1 
  WHEN 2 THEN 2
  WHEN 9 THEN 3
 END
```

Of course, this breaks and says

> "PGError: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must
>   appear in select list"

Is there any way to order your query results in PostgreSQL by the order of the values in the IN clause?

Comment: "_ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list_" - so just move the expression to SELECT list :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can wrap it into a derived table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT id 
  FROM items 
  WHERE id IN (5,2,9) 
) t
ORDER BY
 CASE id
  WHEN 5 THEN 1 
  WHEN 2 THEN 2
  WHEN 9 THEN 3
 END
```

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP):

> **Tip:** Grouping without aggregate expressions effectively calculates the
>   set of distinct values in a column. This can also be achieved using
>   the DISTINCT clause (see [Section 7.3.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-DISTINCT)).

SQL query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM items 
WHERE id IN (5,2,9) 
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY
    CASE id
        WHEN 5 THEN 1 
        WHEN 2 THEN 2
        WHEN 9 THEN 3
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I create this function in postgres PL/PGSQL and it is a lot easier to use.

```
-- Function: uniqueseperategeomarray(geometry[], double precision)

-- DROP FUNCTION uniqueseperategeomarray(geometry[], double precision);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION manualidsort(input_id int, sort_array int[])
  RETURNS int AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
input_index int;
each_item int;
index int;
BEGIN
index := 1;
  FOREACH each_item IN ARRAY sort_array
  LOOP
    IF each_item = input_id THEN
      RETURN index;
    END IF;
    index := index+1;
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
ALTER FUNCTION manualidsort(int, int[])
  OWNER TO staff;
```

And when you run a query, go like this...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY manualidsort(my_table_id, ARRAY[25, 66, 54])
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking around I couldn't find a complete solution to this question.

I think the better solution is to use this query

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE id IN (5,2,9) 
ORDER BY idx(array[5,2,9]::integer[], items.id)
```

If you are using PostgreSQL >= 9.2 you can enable the idx function enabling the extension.

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
```

Otherwise you can create it with the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION idx(anyarray, anyelement)
  RETURNS INT AS 
$$
  SELECT i FROM (
     SELECT generate_series(array_lower($1,1),array_upper($1,1))
  ) g(i)
  WHERE $1[i] = $2
  LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

I really suggest to use `::integer[]` in the query because if you are creating the array dynamically is possible that it has no elements resulting in `ids(array[], items.id)` which would raise an exception on PostgreSQL.