# SQL order by content of IN statement

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ordering by the order of values in a SQL IN() clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause)

I have a simple query statement that pulls properties in a database by zip codes. I use an IN() statement to pass in multiple zip codes. If those zip codes are in order (increasingly further from a target zip code) is it possible to order the results by the order the zip codes are passed into the IN() statement?

For example say i have the zip codes: 77808, 77805, 77806, 77807. I pass them into my query like so

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Properties WHERE zip_code IN('77808', '77805', '77806', '77807',)";
```

Could i order the results by properties that have the zip code of 77808 first, then 77805, then 77806, etc.? or would i need to order it after i pulled it out of the database with PHP(in this case)?

Comment: Mysql? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Mysql, then you could use the [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function.

```
SELECT * FROM Properties 
WHERE zip_code IN('77808', '77805', '77806', '77807')
ORDER BY FIELD(zip_code, '77808', '77805', '77806', '77807')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT 1 as my_order, p.* FROM Properties p WHERE zip_code = '77808'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 as my_order, p.* FROM Properties p WHERE zip_code = '77805'
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3 as my_order, p.* FROM Properties p WHERE zip_code = '77806'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 4 as my_order, p.* FROM Properties p WHERE zip_code = '77807'
) temp_table
ORDER BY my_order ASC
```

Comment: My solution is not very optimal. If you use postgresql, you might be interested by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql