# Use ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'Apple', 'Banana') in django

Tags: django

I would like to use ORDER BY FIELD() (MySQL) in Django. Does Django support that?

So in MySQL it looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM fruit 
ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange'), variety;
```

I would like use this in django ORM. How can i do that. Can i do that using `order_by()`. Or using `extra()` somehow.

Does not work like this:

`Fruit.objects.all().extra(order_by="FIELD(name, 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange')")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A little Google-FU found this: http://davedash.com/2010/02/11/retrieving-elements-in-a-specific-order-in-django-and-mysql/

```
Fruit.objects.extra(
    select={'manual': "FIELD(name, 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange')"},
    order_by=['manual']
)
```

Comment: I was doing google-fu. Maybe you are black belt owner in google-fu? What technique di you use?

Comment: It'll just piss you off, but all I did was search for "django order by field mysql". First result ;)

Comment: Is this portable? I mean, works also in PostgreSQL? My case is something similar, but with a "featured" boolean field. I want to always get the featured items first, and then apply more ordering options.

Comment: No, this will not work with Postgres, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql for some possible workarounds.