# ORDER BY id array in django ORM

Tags: mysql, sql, django

How would I do the following in the django ORM:

```
select * from catalog order by field(id, list_of_ids)
```

So far I have:

```
ids = [1,5,3]
Catalog.objects.extra(order_by=[...?])
```

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: can you show your model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267595/use-order-by-fieldname-apple-banana-in-django) question.

```
Catalog.objects.extra(
    select={'custom_order': 'FIELD(id, %s)' % ','.join(map(str,[1,5,3]))},
    order_by=['custom_order']
)
```