# Most performant way to retrieve a Django queryset sorted in accordance to a redis sorted set

Tags: python, django, sorting, redis

I have a redis sorted set containing object ids and their respective sorting scores. I need to retrieve a Django query set of these objects, sorted in accordance to the sorted set's scores. What's the most efficient way to do this? My DB is postgresql.

---

Currently, I'm retrieving the redis sorted set and the *unsorted* queryset separately. Next, I sort the queryset in accordance to the sorted set's scores in python. Can steps be meaningfully cut here, e.g. somehow sorting the queryset at the point of retrieval, etc.?

```
    obj_ids_with_scr = get_ids_w_scr() #retrieves redis sorted set with scores
    obj_ids = map(itemgetter(0),obj_ids_with_scr) # filters sorted set for just the obj ids
    queryset = Widget.objects.filter(id__in=obj_ids) #unsorted queryset
    a = dict(obj_ids_with_scr) #turning the sorted set into a dictionary
    for obj_pk, sort_score in a:
        obj = queryset.get(id=obj_pk) #get object with id equalling obj_pk 
        sort_score = obj  #assign the object to the 'score' value of this key-value 
    result = a.values() #making a list of all values, that are now in sorted order
    return result
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using postgresql 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using postgres, you can simulate mysql's `order by field` syntax that is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267595/use-order-by-fieldname-apple-banana-in-django) by defining your own [`field` function in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql):

```
CREATE FUNCTION field(anyelement, VARIADIC anyarray) RETURNS numeric AS $$
  SELECT
    COALESCE(
     ( SELECT i FROM generate_subscripts($2, 1) gs(i)
       WHERE $2[i] = $1 ),
     0);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE
```

And then calling with something like:

```
queryset = queryset.extra(
    select={'manual': "FIELD(id, %s)" % (','.join(map(str, obj_ids)),) },
    order_by=['manual']
)
```

---

n.b.  You can also optimize your python code like so if you so choose:

```
widgets = Widgets.objects.in_bulk(obj_ids)
sorted_widgets = [ widgets[x] for x in obj_ids if x in widgets ]
```

In-bulk returns a `dict` mapping `id` to `Widget` instances, which is useful for the type of sorting you are doing.  You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk).

Comment: Thanks for this. The first approach is quite unique - I'm going to try it out. The second is simpler, but what is `in_bulk`? Is it like `filter()`?

Comment: `in_bulk` is like filter in that you can pass it a list of IDs and it will retrieve `Widget`s with those IDs.  It is also special in that it returns a `dict` that maps `id` to the `Widget`.  Kind of shorthand for `{ x.id: x for x in Widgets.objects.filter(id__in=obj_ids) }`.

Comment: I’ve honestly never tried.  But I assume it should work as long as you use it before the `in_bulk` call (e.g., `Widget.objects.select_related('widget_parent').in_bulk(obj_ids)`

Comment: Guess there's only one way to find out. Thanks for the answers!