# Postgres ORDER BY values in IN list using Rails Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, sql-order-by, in-clause

I receive a list of UserIds(about 1000 at a time) sorted by 'Income'. I have User records in "my system's database" but the 'Income' column is not there. I want to retrieve the Users from "my system's database" 
in the Sorted Order as received in the list. I tried doing the following using Active Record expecting that the records would be retrieved in the same order as in the Sorted List but it does not work.

```
//PSEUDO CODE
User.all(:conditions => {:id => [SORTED LIST]})
```

I found an answer to a similar question at the link below, but am not sure how to implement the suggested solution using Active Record.

> [ORDER BY the IN value list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/sql-order-by-the-in-value-list)

Is there any other way to do it?

Please guide.

Shardul.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your linked to answer provides exactly what you need, you just need to code it in Ruby in a flexible manner.

Something like this:

```
class User
  def self.find_as_sorted(ids)
    values = []
    ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
      values << "(#{id}, #{index + 1})"
    end
    relation = self.joins("JOIN (VALUES #{values.join(",")}) as x (id, ordering) ON #{table_name}.id = x.id")
    relation = relation.order('x.ordering')
    relation
  end
end
```

In fact you could easily put that in a module and mixin it into any ActiveRecord classes that need it, since it uses `table_name` and `self` its not implemented with any specific class names.

Comment: How do you deal with `ids` being empty? I've tried this and it seems that in that case you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL users can do this via the `FIELD` function but Postgres lacks it. However this questions has work arounds: [Simulating MySQL's ORDER BY FIELD() in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql)

Comment: Based on the answers in the link above, I would have to create a database function to achieve what I want. Am I right? I am somehow not very comfortable pushing anything to the database (a function or a procedure). Is there some other way to do it?