# Rails postgres order by custom

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am searching for records using an IN query likes so:

```
Event.where("events.id IN (#{events.nil? ? '' : events.collect(&:id).join(',')})")
```

Which produces output like:

```
SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (events.id IN (143,169,139,48,172,146,145,124,111,49,108,18,113,144)) AND (status = 'live') LIMIT 10
```

However, this is then sorted by update_at by default. I'd like it to sort by the IN part of the query. What I mean is that I'd like this to be the order it returns in:

```
143,169,139,48,172,146,145,124,111,49,108,18,113,144
```

Is that possible at all?

I must also note that I can't add a priority column or similar to the table as the "events" part will be dynamically generated.

I've just discovered a very similar question here:

[Postgres ORDER BY values in IN list using Rails Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012574/postgres-order-by-values-in-in-list-using-rails-active-record)

Feel free to mark this one of mine as duplicate

Comment: This question has already been anwsered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/sql-order-by-the-in-value-list

Comment: Use `.order("events.id asc")` in the end.

Comment: Ahh... I didn't see this comment. Then mark as duplicate...

Comment: Not quite a duplicate as this is Rails-specific and I'd like to achieve this with ActiveRecord if possible

Answer (score 2):

This is Rails, so use Rails' methods for database querying. I believe:

```
Event.where(:id => events.map(&:id)).order(:id)
```

is what you're looking for.

If `events` is already a collection of database records, then just `.where(:id => events)` will also work.

Comment: Thanks, I have already thought of something similar but I would prefer to do it with AR if possible.

Comment: What do you mean? That _is_ using AR.

Comment: You are correct, sorry. I ended up using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012574/postgres-order-by-values-in-in-list-using-rails-active-record

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried order by?

```
SELECT "events".* FROM "events" 
WHERE (events.id IN (143,169,139,48,172,146,145,124,111,49,108,18,113,144)) 
AND (status = 'live') 
ORDER BY events.id asc
LIMIT 10
```