# Order by string name from database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I stored string variables in a database, either 'Abstain', 'Block', 'No', or 'Yes'. Currently I am grabbing these using an `ORDER BY position` however, instead of alphabetic order, I would like to order them like: 'Block', 'No', 'Abstain', 'Yes'. Is there an easy way to do this in Rails?

My exact code for this is:

```
def self.unique_votes(motion)
  Vote.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM votes a WHERE created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) as created_at FROM votes b WHERE a.user_id = b.user_id AND motion_id = #{motion.id}) ORDER BY a.position")
end
```

NB: I am using Postgres SQL and am looking for a solution that i can use in the select statement Thanks!

Comment: `Block, No, Abstain, Yes` : how did you define this order?

Comment: I haven't currently they are just strings in the database that is my question how can i define that order instead of alphabetically sorry if this was unclear!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of the ways to do that. By the way, the best way to do such a thing is to have another table named `"Position"` that identifies every value by a number and a foreign key in the `"votes"` table to reference the primary key of `"Position"` table. Also you can have another column named `"Order"` in the `"Position"` table to store those numbers and sort with. You should do these things in the insert time, not on every select.

Cheers

```
SELECT  *
,   Case    a.position
        When    'Block'     Then    0
        When    'No'        Then    1
        When    'Abstain'   Then    2
        When    'Yes'       Then    3
        Else    -1
    End                     As  Position_Value
    FROM    votes   a
    WHERE   created_at =    (
        SELECT  MAX(created_at) as  created_at
            FROM    votes   b
            WHERE   a.user_id   =   b.user_id
            AND motion_id   =   #{motion.id}
    )
    ORDER   BY  Position_Value
```

Any way if it does not work as it should! you can try this one:

```
Select  *
    From    (
        SELECT  *
    ,   Case    a.position
            When    'Block'     Then    0
            When    'No'        Then    1
            When    'Abstain'   Then    2
            When    'Yes'       Then    3
            Else    -1
        End                     As  Position_Value
        FROM    votes   a
        WHERE   created_at =    (
            SELECT  MAX(created_at) as  created_at
                FROM    votes   b
                WHERE   a.user_id   =   b.user_id
                AND motion_id   =   #{motion.id}
        )
    )   As  Result
    ORDER   BY  Position_Value
```

Comment: Have tried this exact wording out in my application and it did not work is "As Position_Value" supposed to be out of the switch statement? This seems like the best way for me to do this.

Comment: "it did not work" is not a complete reference for me to know what happened there. Could you please tell me what was the error?

Comment: Sorry there was no error in the code side, but there seems to be no ordering applied. The statement i had was ordering it just the wrong way.

Comment: What is the order? it should be in order from 0 (Block) to 3 (Yes).

Comment: Seems random with my test page its goes: Yes, Block, Block, Abstain, Yes, Abstain, No.

Comment: What version of SQL you are using sir?

Comment: PostGres sorry should have stated that!

Comment: @LearningDev What do you mean I should have stated that? That refers to what?

Comment: I just mean i should have told everyone what database i was using in the question sorry.

Comment: Ah, I got it. It's ok, just help me to solve the problem. What is the version?

Comment: Execute this "Select @@Version" and paste the value here please. Thank you.

Comment: Using Postgres 9.1 sorry i couldn't find anywhere to do the @@version but went to my Postgres on machine and its 9.1

Comment: It's because you are not using SQL Server. Try the second code I just updated in the answer see what happens.

Comment: So turns out i was the one being the idiot your first code worked but my variables where different then what i said no capitals at front sorry for the hassle thank you so much =)

Comment: You can put the CASE right into the ORDER BY if you don't need the position.

Comment: Thanks for that @mu is too short makes it quite nice and clean =)

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I have a series I need to sort into an unnatural order, I add an additional integer field, and put values into it that will force the string values into whatever order I want them.

Instead of having only:

```
'Abstain'
'Block'
'No'
'Yes'
```

I'd have a second field:

```
'Abstain' 3
'Block'   1
'No'      2
'Yes'     4
```

Sorting on the second column allows me to retrieve the values in my desired order:

```
'Block'   1
'No'      2
'Abstain' 3
'Yes'     4
```

Comment: Thanks for that a very valid and useful suggestion however i really cant change the database schema (at this stage anyway)

Comment: This is what I do in my applications as well.

Comment: @LearningDev, Then you should put that criteria into your question.

Comment: Sorry still new to this @the Tin Man will get the hang of it didn't mean to be ambiguous but this will definitely help me in the future thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a permanent requirement, you can store them in a different table with another column 'ordering' that carries the number to print them in desired order, join your results with this table and ORDER BY the ordering column.

If this is a temporary, you can join your results with `UNION` of bunch of SQL statements that select the value and the ordering and then order by the ordering column.

Comment: So the suggestion is that I should create a temporary ordering table? This is not a permanent requirement and should only apply to the one part of a much bigger application, I have seen some stuff about an "ORDER BY" statement that can sort the strings out is this a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

You could define something like MySQL's `FIELD` function, ie an index lookup into an array, then use that for your `ORDER BY`. It's a bit more concise than an array.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12366184/398670