# Converting an array of objects to ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an array of objects, let's call it an `Indicator`. I want to run Indicator class methods (those of the `def self.subjects` variety, scopes, etc) on this array. The only way I know to run class methods on a group of objects is to have them be an ActiveRecord::Relation. So I end up resorting to adding a `to_indicators` method to `Array`.

```
def to_indicators
  # TODO: Make this less terrible.
  Indicator.where id: self.pluck(:id)
end
```

At times I chain quite a few of these scopes to filter down the results, within the class methods. So, even though I call a method on an ActiveRecord::Relation, I don't know how to access that object. I can only get to the contents of it through `all`. But `all` is an Array. So then I have to convert that array to a ActiveRecord::Relation. For example, this is part of one of the methods:

```
all.to_indicators.applicable_for_bank(id).each do |indicator|
  total += indicator.residual_risk_for(id)
  indicator_count += 1 if indicator.completed_by?(id)
end
```

I guess this condenses down to two questions.

1. How can I convert an Array of objects to an ActiveRecord::Relation? Preferably without doing a `where` each time.
2. When running a `def self.subjects` type method on an ActiveRecord::Relation, how do I access that ActiveRecord::Relation object itself?

Thanks. If I need to clarify anything, let me know.

Comment: If your only reason for trying to convert that array back to a relation is because you got it via `.all`, just use `.scoped` like Andrew Marshall's answer indicates (Although in rails 4 it'll work with `.all`).  If you find yourself needing to turn an array into a relation you've gone wrong somewhere...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> How can I convert an Array of objects to an ActiveRecord::Relation? Preferably without doing a where each time.

You cannot convert an Array to an ActiveRecord::Relation since a Relation is just a builder for a SQL query and its methods do not operate on actual data.

However, if what you want is a relation then:

- for ActiveRecord 3.x, don’t call `all` and instead call [`scoped`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scoped), which will give back a Relation which represents the same records that `all` would give you in an Array.
- for ActiveRecord 4.x, simply call [`all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-all), which returns a Relation.

> When running a `def self.subjects` type method on an ActiveRecord::Relation, how do I access that ActiveRecord::Relation object itself?

When the method is called on a Relation object, `self` is the relation (as opposed to the model class it’s defined in).

Comment: See @Marco Prins below about the solution.

Comment: what about .push deprecated method in rails 5

Comment: @GstjiSaini I’m unsure of the exact method you’re referring to, please provide doc or source link. Though, if it’s deprecated, not a very viable solution as it’ll likely go away soon.

Comment: And that's why you can do `class User; def self.somewhere; where(location: "somewhere"); end; end`, then `User.limit(5).somewhere`

Comment: This is the only answer that is truly enlightening the OP. The question reveals flawed knowledge of how ActiveRecord works. @Justin is just reinforcing a lack of understanding about why it’s bad to keep passing arrays of objects around just to map over them and build another unnecessary  query.

Answer (score 197):

You can convert an array of objects `arr` to an ActiveRecord::Relation like this (assuming you know which class the objects are, which you probably do)

```
MyModel.where(id: arr.map(&:id))
```

You have to use `where` though, it's a useful tool which you shouldn't be reluctant to use. And now you have a one-liner converting an array to a relation.

How it works:

`map(&:id)` will turn your array of objects to an array containing only their id's. And passing an array to a `where` clause will generate a SQL `IN` statement that looks something like:

```
SELECT .... WHERE `my_models`.id IN (2, 3, 4, 6, ....
```

*Keep in mind that the ordering of the array will be lost* - But since your objective is only to run a class method on the *collection* of these objects, I assume it won't be a problem.

Comment: Well done, exactly what I needed.  You can use this for any attribute on the model. works perfectly for me.

Comment: Why build literal SQL yourself when you can do `where(id: arr.map(&:id))`? And strictly speaking, this doesn’t convert the array to a relation, but instead gets new instances of the objects (once the relation is realized) with those IDs which may have different attribute values than the already in-memory instances in the array.

Comment: This loses the ordering, though.

Comment: @VelizarHristov That's because it's now a relation, which can only be ordered by a column, and not any way you want. Relations are faster to handle large data sets, and there will be some trade-offs.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. But can anyone shed some light on the efficiency of this approach? Doesn't seem to be the most efficient thing to reiterate through the entire array. Nonetheless works for me.

Comment: Very inefficient! You've turned a collection of objects you already have in memory into ones you are going to do a database query to access. I would look at refactoring those class methods you are wanting to iterate over the array.

Comment: @james2m can you think of a more efficient way to convert any array of objects to an active record relation? As far as i know there's no in-built method or way to do this in rails. This is the most practical approach in Rails.

Comment: @MarcoPrins THANK YOU. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

Well, in my case, I need to **converting an array of objects to ActiveRecord::Relation** as well as **sorting** them with a specific column(id for instance). Since I'm using MySQL, the **field function** could be helpful.

```
MyModel.where('id in (?)',ids).order("field(id,#{ids.join(",")})")
```

The SQL looks like:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (id in (11,5,6,7,8,9,10))  
ORDER BY field(id,11,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

[MySQL field function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

Comment: For a version of this that works with PostgreSQL, look no further than this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::TooManyArguments: ERROR:  cannot pass more than 100 arguments to a function)

This workaround can not stand over 100 arguments to a function, thus, it works with relations of total length up to 100, ids like 112 and 12 won't be separated from each other.

Comment: So `MyModel.where(id: ids)` ?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this is NOT a silver bullet. Out of my experience, I found that converting to relation is sometimes easier than alternatives. I try to use this approach very sparingly and only in cases where the alternative would be more complex.

That being said here is my solution, I've extended `Array` class

```rb
# lib/core_ext/array.rb

class Array

  def to_activerecord_relation
    return ApplicationRecord.none if self.empty?

    clazzes = self.collect(&:class).uniq
    raise 'Array cannot be converted to ActiveRecord::Relation since it does not have same elements' if clazzes.size > 1

    clazz = clazzes.first
    raise 'Element class is not ApplicationRecord and as such cannot be converted' unless clazz.ancestors.include? ApplicationRecord

    clazz.where(id: self.collect(&:id))
  end
end
```

A usage example would be `array.to_activerecord_relation.update_all(status: 'finished')`. Now where do I use it?

Sometimes you need to filter out `ActiveRecord::Relation` for example take out not completed elements. In those cases best is to use scope `elements.not_finished` and you would still keep `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

But sometimes that condition is more complex. Take out all elements that are not finished, and that has been produced in the last 4 weeks and have been inspected. To avoid creating new scopes you can filter to an array and then convert back. Keep in mind that you still do a query to DB, quick since it searches by `id` but still a query.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord::Relation` binds database query which retrieves data from database.

Suppose to make sense, We have array with objects of same class, then with which query we suppose to bind them?

When I run,

```
users = User.where(id: [1,3,4,5])
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (1, 3, 4, 5)  ORDER BY created_at desc
```

Here in above, `users`return `Relation` object but binds database query behind it and you can view it,

```
users.to_sql
 => "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (1, 3, 4, 5)  ORDER BY created_at desc"
```

So it is not possible to return `ActiveRecord::Relation` from array of objects which is independent of sql query.

Answer (score 0):

**In PostgreSQL, to maintain the order** (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1310188/6439240)), given `arr` of objects:

```
ids = arr.pluck(:id)
cases = ids.map.with_index { |id, index| "WHEN id='#{id}' THEN #{index + 1}" }.join(" ")
Model.where(id: ids).order(Arel.sql("CASE #{cases} ELSE #{ids.size + 1} END"))
```

Example produced SQL:

```
SELECT "records".*
FROM "records"
WHERE "records"."id"
IN (
  '84b61039-193b-4263-9de6-5185e2cf4e06',
  '5955c8d0-a809-4e13-b15a-ac3a1b17569e',
  '37c44652-3195-4839-8130-409bb4c3a564'
  )
ORDER BY
  CASE
  WHEN id='84b61039-193b-4263-9de6-5185e2cf4e06' THEN 1
  WHEN id='5955c8d0-a809-4e13-b15a-ac3a1b17569e' THEN 2
  WHEN id='37c44652-3195-4839-8130-409bb4c3a564' THEN 3
  ELSE 4
END;
```

*Note*: it won't work with `.distinct`; in this scenario use `ids = arr.pluck(:id).uniq!`