# How to convert array to ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am loading some data with

```
data = Product.find_by_sql(sql)
```

so it  is returning array. But, i further want  to chain some model methods like `order`, `where` . I guess this is only possible if i change/convert this array into `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` object.

How can i ?

Comment: shouldn't you be doing that in your sql, that will make it efficient and reduce the overhead of data manipulation after fetching.

Comment: yes, i agree but that is not the condition. The above question is not the actual code. It is much more complex. I often came across such situation where i have do do this.

Comment: I don't think you can convert an array object to a CollectionProxy

Comment: It's possible if you have the object id. Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331862/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-activerecordrelation