# Optimizing ActiveRecord query when there is if/else logic in select statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a very janky query that I'm trying to optimize. I want to return an activerecord association of user records based on some membership packet logic.

```
ids = User.joins(:memberships).includes(:memberships).select do |user|
  if user.memberships.count <= 1
    user.membership_packet_sent_at.blank?
  else
    user.membership_packet_sent_at.blank? && user.current_membership.created_more_than_30_days_ago?
  end
end.uniq.map(&:id)

User.where(id: ids)
```

The issue I am running into above is that I have to make two queries since I don't know how to use select to return an active record association instead of an array.

1. How do I return an activerecord association from select?
2. Is there a better way for me to organize my logic inside the select block?

Edit:

After some refactoring, I was able to move some of the select logic into methods:

```

```
ids = User.joins(:memberships)
          .where(membership_packet_sent_at: nil)
          .select(&:current_membership_packet_expired?)
          .uniq
          .map(&:id)

User.where(id: ids)
```

```

Still running into the issue of how to return an activerecord association instead

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say this is very janky. The main optimization error beginners usually have is N+1 (queries inside an iteration), which you've prevented via `preload`.

Comment: @maxple fair point. after cleaning up the method in select and reading aegis's solution, it made more sense. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is currently possible to directly return a `Relation` object after applying a `select`.

These are the main reasons that I could think about:

- A `Relation` object is just a SQL builder and doesn't work with the actual data
- The `select` method allows to execute custom processes that cannot be represented as a valid SQL query, so it won't be possible to chain the result of the `select` with another query like `where`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331862/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-activerecordrelation) also states a similar line of thought.