# find_by_sql to something that returns an activeRecords relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need find_by_sql to return a ActiveRecord::Relation object. It seems to be not possible. Then I want to write my query in pure ruby.

I have a table with a relationship with itself:

```
class Alarma < ApplicationRecord
  **belongs_to :root, class_name: "Alarma", foreign_key: "relacionada_id", optional: true
  has_many :children, class_name: "Alarma" , foreign_key: "relacionada_id"**
```

This is the table:

```
create_table "alarmas", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "sysname"
    t.string   "component"
    t.string   "details"
    t.integer  "estado_id"
    t.integer  "relacionada_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.index ["estado_id"], name: "index_alarmas_on_estado_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["severity_id"], name: "index_alarmas_on_severity_id", using: :btree
  end
```

And this is my query in sql:

```
  Alarma.find_by_sql("SELECT a1.*  FROM alarmas a1 LEFT OUTER JOIN alarmas a2 ON a1.relacionada_id=a2.id 
WHERE a1.estado_id IN (1,2) OR a2.estado_id IN (1,2)")
```

The Alarma could be root, and then it has children alarms, or it could be in state: estado_id = 2 what means it is a child, and has a root alarm, (this alarm is relacionada_id).

Example:

Root alarm, relacionada_id = null, id = 99
Child alarm, relacionada_id = 99, id = 112

What I need is the list of alarms, in state estado_id = 1 or 2, and the alarms who his root is in the state estado id 1 or 2 (and his state )

I could get it work with my own sql query using find_by_sql but it returns an array, and I need a ActiveRecord::Relation object because I need to continue working with the result ( because I use a pagination gem and order and page methods don't work with an array)

Comment: The code in find_by_sql solves my problem. The thing is that I need to continue working with the result (pagination and order using a gem) and this result should be an ActiveRecord Relation. I have no experience in Sql, and with complex queries in rails, I could get it in pure sql doing the left outer join I have no idea how to write it in a rails way.

Comment: @Bri4n Whats the association between `Alaram`, `Estado` and `Relacionada`?

Comment: I edited my question to be a little more clear. Thanks @Kavincat

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [Converting an array of objects to ActiveRecord::Relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331862/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-activerecordrelation)

The trick is that you take the ids of the results of the raw SQL statement, and perform a second query using `where` so it returns a `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

```
as_array = Alarma.find_by_sql("SELECT a1.*  FROM alarmas a1 LEFT OUTER JOIN alarmas a2 ON a1.relacionada_id=a2.id WHERE a1.estado_id IN (1,2) OR a2.estado_id IN (1,2)")

as_relation = Alarma.where(id: as_array.map(&:id))
```

Comment: This requires you to load all the id's into memory which is rather inefficient

Comment: Another problem here is if you have some ordering in raw sql, with converting it to AR it will overwrite it with default order scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `from()` method to get the data from a subquery so it gets the records from a temp table:

```
subquery = "SELECT a1.*  FROM alarmas a1 LEFT OUTER JOIN alarmas a2 ON a1.relacionada_id=a2.id WHERE a1.estado_id IN (1,2) OR a2.estado_id IN (1,2)"

records = Alarma.from("(#{subquery}) temp_table_alias") #=> ActiveRecord relation

records.to_sql #=> "SELECT * FROM (subquery) temp_table_alias"
```

Answer (score 0):

To tack-on to the previous answer, to order the relation by the same order as whatever the original SQL was ordered by, you would define this scope on the model:

```
  # NOTE: should be applied AFTER! all order statements
  scope :by_ordered_ids, -> (column_name, ordered_ids, type = 'INT') do
    ordered_ids_s = ordered_ids.join(',')
    joins(<<~SQL).order('y.index')
      JOIN (
        SELECT x.arr[x.index] AS id, x.index
          FROM (SELECT arr, GENERATE_SUBSCRIPTS(arr, 1) AS index
                  FROM (SELECT '{#{ordered_ids_s}}'::#{type}[]) T(arr)) x
      ) y ON #{table_name}.#{column_name} = y.id
    SQL
  end
```

... and then use like so:

```
as_relation = Alarma.where(id: as_array.map(&:id)).by_ordered_ids(:id_column, as_array.map(&:id))
```