# Rails iterate on a collection and return it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to do a map on a rails collection but I need the result to be an active record collection instead of array. Currently I am doing the following but this returns an array.

```
MyModel.all.map do |model|
  model.tap do |m|
    response = fetcher.new.call(m.name)
    m.rating = response[:rating]
  end
end
```

Comment: Similar queston: [Converting an array of objects to ActiveRecord::Relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331862/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-activerecordrelation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an array of objects to ActiveRecord::Relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331862/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-activerecordrelation)

Comment: Are you trying to actually update those models?

Answer (score 1):

```rb
# 1. get all the records 
all_records = MyModel.all

# 2. Iterate over the collection and modify each model as you are doing
all_records.each do |model|
  response = fetcher.new.call(model.name)
  model.rating = response[:rating]
end

# 3. Return the modified collection
all_records
```

Comment: `map` is unnecessary you could use `each` instead and avoid creating a potentially very large `Array` that is never used. Also `tap` is not needed either as the exact same result could be achieved by just using `model` that was yielded to the block since `m === model`

Comment: True. I tried to show the quick changes to make it work. I just modified it as per your suggestion.

Comment: I was just thinking maybe `tap` isn't terrible it should just be `all_records.tap {|ar| ar.each {#...}}` but this is essentially identical to just returning `all_records` afterwards as you have shown.