# Get all nested records for multiple activerecords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Lets say there are two models: `User` and `Post` where each post belongs to a user and a user can have many posts.

If you do `@user.posts` you get all posts for `@user`. But, given `@users`, is there a more elegant way than `Post.where(user_id: @users.map(&:id))` to get all posts for `@users`? Something like `@users.posts`?

Comment: Is `@users` an `ActiveRecord::Relation` or an array of objects? If an array, the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331862/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-activerecordrelation may help...

Comment: @users is an ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: In that case the answer I gave should work; `Post.where(user: @users)`... If it's not quite what you need, please edit your question to include a code sample of what you've already tried and what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment that `@users` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, the simplest method is to let Active Record figure it out for you:

```rb
Post.where(user: @users)
# SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" IN
#   (SELECT "user"."id" FROM "users")
```

This performs a single database query and lets the database do all the heavy lifting with a sub-select (your sub-select might look different... in my example `@users` was simply `User.all`).

For cases when you aren't using `.map` to get an id field, you might want to consider [`.pluck`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) to return an array of values from the database without fetching entire records. For example:

```rb
@users.pluck(:name)

# instead of

@users.map(&:name)
```

In theory you can use `.pluck` in your scenario but if you have a lot of users you'll generate and send a very long SQL query containing an array of user IDs instead of letting the database do the work itself...

```rb
Post.where(user_id: @users.pluck(:id))
# SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" IN
#   (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 72, 73, 71, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 97)
```