# Sort by specific ids in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have inherited another programmer's Rails3 project, and I'm fairly new to rails overall. He's got a query that appears to sort by specific id's. Can somebody explain how this resolves in actual SQL? I think this code is killing the db and subsequently rails. I've tried to output it in the logger but can't seem to get the actual SQL to output even with config set to :debug.  Searching heavily here (on SO) didn't turn up a clear explanation of how this query looks.  The code looks like:

```
options = {
              select: "SUM(1) AS num_demos, product_id ",
              group:  "product_id",                
              order:  "num_demos ASC",
            }
  product_ids = Demo.where("state = 'waitlisted'").find(:all, options).collect{|d| d.product_id}
  sort_product_ids = product_ids.collect{|product_id| "id = #{product_id}"}   
  Product.where(visible: true, id: product_ids).order(sort_product_ids.join(', '))
```

As far as I can see, the final line will create a query against the product table with an ORDER BY "id = 1, id = 3, ..." etc, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me. All clues appreciated.

Comment: use `to_sql` at the end of the query and inspect it to see the SQL generated

Comment: Thanks, got same output from rails console. It looks like this: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."visible" = 't' AND "products"."id" IN (166, 105,..etc) ORDER BY id = 166, id = 105, id = 110, id = 99, id = 109, id = 118, id = 108, id = 160,... etc.  I've not seen this type of ORDER BY before, and it's pretty cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick breakdown of what's going on, as it'll help you understand what to do for your replacement query.

```
options = {
              select: "SUM(1) AS num_demos, product_id ",
              group:  "product_id",                
              order:  "num_demos ASC",
            }
product_ids = Demo.where("state = 'waitlisted'").find(:all, options).collect{|d| d.product_id}
```

This line will generate

```
SELECT SUM(1) as num_demos, product_id FROM "demos" WHERE (state = 'waitlisted') GROUP BY product_id
```

And returns an array of `Demo` objects, sorted by the `count(*)` of rows in the group, where only the `product_id` attribute has been loaded, and is available to you.

Next,

```
sort_product_ids = product_ids.collect{|product_id| "id = #{product_id}"}
```

results in a collection of product_ids mapped to the format `"id = x"`. IE: If the previous result returned 10 results, with product_ids ranging from 1..10, `sort_product_ids` is now equivalent to `["id = 1", "id = 2", "id = 3", "id = 4", "id = 5", "id = 6", "id = 7", "id = 8", "id = 9", "id = 10"]`

Finally,

```
Product.where(visible: true, id: product_ids).order(sort_product_ids.join(', '))
```

Selects all `Products` where the column `visible` is `true`, and their `id` is in the array of `product_ids` (which, as we found out earlier, is actually an array of `Demo` objects, not integers - this might be causing the query to fail). Then, it asks SQL to sort that result list by the `sort_product_ids` (sent in as a string `"id = 1, id = 2, ... id = 10"` instead of an array `["id = 1", "id = 2", ... "id = 10"]`).

More info available at: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html

Comment: thank you for this useful analysis. In my tests in irb, the array sort_product_ids would have entries like "id = 1", "id = 2", etc. When you call join(', ') on that you should get a single string with all those entries thus: "id = 1, id = 2", etc. So does ActiveRecord actually create SQL that says ... ORDER BY ('id = 1, id = 2, ...') ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Morner. Would like to vote this answer up but I don't have enough reputation...

Comment: No problem, did your question get resolved? Select am answer if so

Comment: Almost. I finally got rails console working (had to set env vars for DATABASE_URL and RAILS_ENV correctly, for anybody reading this that is struggling to do that), and then ran the above code in the console. It pretty much does what you said, but interestingly, the records are returned in the reverse order from the list created by the join on sort_product_ids. Why would that be?

Comment: Not sure, but you can reverse that by appending one of `"ASC"` or `"DESC"` to the `sort_product_ids.join(', ')` string; whichever results in the opposite sorting.

Comment: you cna reverse it by using `sort_product_ids.reverse.join(', ')` in `order`

Answer (score 3):

To select and sort by a given array of ids you can use this

```
Product.where(visible: true, id: product_ids)
.order( "field(id,#{product_ids.join(',')})" )
```

Comment: Do you mean, it will select only the records with the given ids and return them in the order of the ids as provided by product_ids.join(',') ?

Comment: it will select the records with the given ids and `visible = true`. Then it will arrange them by the given order. If a `product` is not present in the final result it will just ignore its `id` in the order.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It ordered my Model by a given set of ids.

Comment: @tihom This helped but I'm getting: `(PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: ...,2,3,4,9532,9533,88,89)) ORDER BY FIELD(stage_id, [1, 2, 3, ...`

Comment: @sscirrus the `order by field` functionality is not available in PG see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PostgreSQL, consider to use `WITH ORDINALITY`, it is the fastest way compared to others. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35456954/1009442).

To apply this method to Ruby on Rails, for example:

```rb
class SpecifiedByIds
  def specified_by_ids(ids)
    joins(
      <<~SQL
        LEFT JOIN unnest(array[#{ids.join(',')}])
        WITH ORDINALITY AS t(id,odr) ON t.id = #{table_name}.id
      SQL
    ).order('t.odr')
  end
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend SpecifiedByIds
end
```

Comment: this works with rails 6 and PostgreSQL database