# Activerecord ORDER BY FIELD

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to do a `"ORDER BY FIELD"` in active record. I know that i can do it with `MySQL` but i am trying to keep my app agnostic and follow best practice. my production db is `PostgreSQL`

the MySQL looks like

```
SELECT id, name
FROM mytable
WHERE name IN ('B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C')
ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C')
```

Comment: Asked and answered I think : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql

Comment: Thanks that helps but i don't want to Simulating MySQL's in PG but i want to be able to do it with active record. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to make it happen and this is what i came with. I still think that this can be a bit cleaner

```
Model.select(:id).select(:name).order("status = 'B' DESC, status = 'A' DESC, status = 'D' DESC, status = 'E' DESC, status = 'C' DESC")
```

Comment: Use a CASE statement like in the duplicate.

Comment: @muistooshort how would you add a case statement on the order?

Comment: Exactly the way [the dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql) does: `order("case status when 'B' ...")`. AR doesn't solve all your database portability needs, not even close.

Comment: I just released this gem which bundles this functionality: https://github.com/panorama-ed/order_as_specified

Answer (score 1):

One agnostic option is to move your status values into another model and have an extra attribute for the sort order.

Comment: Thanks i like that solution. and if i could not get this to work that is what i am going to do