# Postgres error when trying to display all items through a relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-postgresql, pg

This works on SQLite3, but not on PostgreSQL.

The error I'm getting is `PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

I'm trying to display all `exercises` that are in a `group` with the code: `current_user.group.exercises`

Here is the relationship

A group has_many workouts, and a workout has_many exercises

In my Group model I have `has_many :exercises, through: :workouts`

Any ideas?

EDIT 1:

Here is the SQL rails is generating:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "exercises".* 
FROM "exercises" 
  INNER JOIN "workout_exercises" ON "exercises"."id" = "workout_exercises"."exercise_id" 
  INNER JOIN "workouts" ON "workout_exercises"."workout_id" = "workouts"."id" 
  INNER JOIN "groups_workouts" ON "workouts"."id" = "groups_workouts"."workout_id" 
WHERE "groups_workouts"."group_id" = 2 
ORDER BY exercise_order, workout_order
```

And here is the error:

```
PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ..." WHERE "groups_workouts"."group_id" = 2 ORDER BY exercise_o...
                                                             ^
: SELECT DISTINCT "exercises".* FROM "exercises" INNER JOIN "workout_exercises" ON "exercises"."id" = "workout_exercises"."exercise_id" INNER JOIN "workouts" ON "workout_exercises"."workout_id" = "workouts"."id" INNER JOIN "groups_workouts" ON "workouts"."id" = "groups_workouts"."workout_id" WHERE "groups_workouts"."group_id" = 2 ORDER BY exercise_order, workout_order
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each SQL variant has slightly different rules as to what expressions it accepts. For example, see [Simulating MySQL's ORDER BY FIELD() in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql) and related links for information on this issue. If you give the specifics of the SQL you're generating, you can probably get more specific advice.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my question to include the SQL that rails is generating, and the PSQL error. 

I'm also taking a look at the link now.

Answer (score 3):

So this is a `uniq` constraint exception. On the model I had `has_many :exercises, through: :workouts, uniq: true` which Postgres didn't like.

To fix the error, I moved the `uniq` constraint from the model to the actual query. So in this situation, I just did `current_user.group.exercises.uniq`

This only sort of solves my problem. There are situations where I would want to have a uniq constraint at the model level, but I haven't been able to find a way to do that yet.