# Laravel: order by where in

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sphinx

I am using SphinxSearch to query some contents and have the ids of my objects that I want to query with MySQL. The array of my ids are sorted depending on their rank Sphinx gives.
Thus, I would like to make a MySQL like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,17,2) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id,1,17,2)
```

I know I can do:

```
Table::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

But I can't get the order I had.

How can I do that in a proper way with Laravel ?

Comment: Look into `orderByRaw`.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

## Solution:

```
$ids = array(1,17,2);
 
$ids_ordered = implode(',', $ids);
 
$items = static::whereIn('id', $ids)
 ->orderByRaw("FIELD(id, $ids_ordered)")
 ->get();
```

## Additional Notes:

Using the solution found on an article titled [Get all items at once ordered by the current order of ids in the WHERE IN clause using Eloquent](https://web.archive.org/web/20140213195301/http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/get-all-items-at-once-ordered-by-the-current-order-of-ids-in-the-where-in-clause-using-eloquent):

> Useful when you want to orderBy the items from the database using the order of id's in the array you supplied in the WHERE IN clause. Can be easily modified to suit your needs, like provide a different order of ids to be used.

```
// Raw SQL:
// SELECT * FROM items WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5) ORDER BY FIELD(id,1,2,3,4,5);
 
$itemIds = array(1,2,3,4,5);
 
$ids = implode(',', $itemIds);
 
$items = static::whereIn('id', $itemIds)
    ->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $ids)"))
    ->take($limit)
    ->get();
```

Comment: This is pure gold

Comment: $ids_ordered = implode(',', $itemIds); to $ids_ordered = implode(',', $ids);

Comment: this only works on mysql. I had to use php to sort because I use postgres

Comment: As stated in the original post, this was a question specifically about MySQL. You can try to change the raw SQL with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866465/order-by-the-in-value-list

Comment: This is incredible!

Comment: Is there a Postgres version? FIELD isn't available for that database.

Answer (score 9):

I got this problem too, but my target array elements were strings. in this case ...

```
$strings = array('xxx','yyy','zzz');

$imploded_strings = implode("','", $strings);

$items = static::whereIn('some_column', $strings)
->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(some_column, '$imploded_strings')"))
->get();
```

Comment: What worked for me was:

`$searchedStrings = "'".implode("', '", $originalArrayOfStrings)."'";`

Comment: Do you have a Postgres friendly version. FIELD isn't available for it.

Comment: dear Riza Khan, here you can read more about this feature in Postgres:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql

Answer (score -1):

```
$category_id = Category::select('id')->orderby('name','ASC')->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Comment: Long lines like this often benefit from line-wrapping `:-)`.