# Retrieve Eloquent models in the ID order passed to whereIn

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
Post::whereIn('id', [3, 4, 1, 2])->paginate(10);
```

And the result I get is in the following order (ids I mean):

1, 2, 3, 4 ...

Is it possible to somehow get the result in the order of how ids are passed to the query?

Comment: Not answering your question, but just so you know, in case you don't know why this is happening: relational databases don't have the concept of "order". You don't get an ordered list of results, but a tuple (set) of results.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking this is a mySQL thing, rather than Laravel.. But perhaps there is a solution..

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704575/laravel-order-by-where-in) out, does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Probabyl you need to sort then in the query like this:

```
Post::whereIn('id', [3, 4, 1, 2])->orderBy('id')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

**read laravel doc from this link for whereIn()** 
you didnt make any objects of your POST model
make an object and work with it, its better this way

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-wherein

Comment: The problem is that I have to work with Query Builder, not the collection. Because the collection cannot be paginated and my project uses Dingo API and expects a query builder paginator..