# orderBy field name in laravel query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to order the query value based on status order 8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.I have the query.Is is possible to sort by given value. I want to order the query result in the given order 8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

```
$query->orderBy('status','DESC')  //order by 8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
->get();
```

Comment: More explanation please ?

Comment: I want to order the query result in the given order 8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: are they row id's 8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: You can play around with collection since you are ordering it with status first fetch the first record and in the for loop  start from end till 2nd element

Comment: not row id,field -status id

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704575/laravel-order-by-where-in

Comment: Try: `orderByRaw()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `orderByRaw()` method