# Order a set of results by an externally calculated score

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a site that fetches the ID and SCORE of records for a user from an external source.

I want to then fetch the records that match the ID's, ordered by each ID's SCORE.

The ID's and SCORES come to the app as XML which I'm currently parsing into an array (of hashes):

```
[{90=>279}, {32=>400}]
```

How can I use that score to order the records returned?

Comment: Try to be more specific and give examples of how you've tried to solve this.

Comment: Yes, i know that's the usual thing but sometimes the question is  "where the hell do i even start."

Comment: @gernberg - anything constructive to add?

Comment: What format is the data you receive?

Comment: XML, which is easy to parse, so i end up with an array of ID's & Scores.

Comment: Can you add (in an edit to your question) an example "array of ID's & Scores" please?

Comment: ok @MaxWilliams - i've updated with an example

Comment: Which dbms are you using?  (MySQL, Postgres, SQLite etc)

Comment: I'm using postgres @MaxWilliams

Comment: See my EDIT to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
src_data = [{90=>279}, {32=>400}] 
ids = src_data.sort_by{|hash| hash.values.first}.reverse.collect(&:keys).flatten   
# => [32,90]
```

ids should now be an array of ids, in order of highest score to lowest score.  Now we can do the find.

```
@users = User.where("id in (?)", ids).order("ORDER BY FIELD(ID,#{ids.join(',')})")
```

This should generate sql like

```
select * from users where id in (32,90) ORDER BY FIELD(ID,32,90);
```

which should give you the users back in the right order.

EDIT - for postgres

Postgresql doesn't have the `field()` function.  You can define your own, see [Simulating MySQL's ORDER BY FIELD() in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql), but you might prefer to not bother and just reorder the results after you get them:

```
@users = User.where("id in (?)", ids).sort_by{|user| ids.index(user.id)}
```

Comment: thanks max.  This got me through and is easily extendable when I need to manipulate the score or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a standard ruby array you should be able to sort it by using "sort_by".

Two examples of sorting based on the keys / values:

```
results = [{90=>279}, {32=>400}] 

results.sort_by{|result| result.keys[0]}
# => [{32=>400}, {90=>279}] 

results.sort_by{|result| result.values[0]}
# => [{90=>279}, {32=>400}]
```

Check this blogpost on more information regarding sort_by and sort in Ruby:
http://brandon.dimcheff.com/2009/11/18/rubys-sort-vs-sort-by.html

Comment: Right, sorry I see where the confusion is.  I want to fetch the records that match the ID's ordered by the SCORE's.  I've updated the question

Comment: @Will Is that more what you are looking for?