# Sort Laravel Collection by custom order, other than asc or desc

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this array as Laravel Collection :

```
"data": [
  {
    "id": 863368,
    "reference": "Ref 1",
    "status": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 863391,
    "reference": "Ref 2",
    "status": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 863390,
    "reference": "Ref 3",
    "status": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 863396,
    "reference": "Ref 4",
    "status": 3
  }
];
```

And I need to sort it by `status`, not by `asc` or `desc`, but the records with status `2` should be first on the list, then status `1` then status `3`.

I can't figure out how to achive this, thank you in advance.

Comment: Oh, try it:
->orderByRaw('FIELD(status,2,1,3)')

Comment: can status only be 1,2 or 3? Or there are more than 3 status?

Comment: i think you need a highly repeated  status order .Right? 2(2 times),1,3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi had similar issue,

```
$final = $collection->sortBy(function($item){
    return array_search($item->status, ['2', '1', '3']);
});
```

`['2', '1', '3']` (Status with number 2 will be first because his position key is 0, just change the order as you need.

Or you can create an `array` like `['2' => 1, '1' => 2, '3' => 3]`

use like `return $arry_of_order[$item->status];` (faster then calling `array_search` each time)

---

**P.S.** If you can use **Database** (in case MySQL), as other people here suggested, you should stick to it, `$query->orderByRaw("FIELD(status, '2', '1', '3')")`

For PostgreSQL look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql)

Comment: This solution is good for a small number of collection. If a collection is too large using MySQL's ordering will be better :)

Comment: @MihirBhende The question was about `laravel collection` not DB, but yes ordering from DB will be faster.

Comment: I agree and your solution is totally correct, just considering the possibility of this collection built from a query, I felt to mention this

Comment: @MihirBhende thank you, I updated my answer, so TS can take this into consideration.

Answer (score 4):

You can get this by using `orderByRaw`

```
Model::orderByRaw('FIELD(status, 2, 1, 3)')->get();
```

Also By using `orderBy`

```
Model::orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(status, 2, 1, 3))'))->get();
```

Comment: I receive and error if I try to use this: lluminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') asc' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `scenarios` order by FIELD(status, 2, 1, 3)) asc) in file /home/vagrant/code/projectresourceonline/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 671

Comment: Do you have code that is compatible with Postgres? FIELD is an invalid function

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting data from MySQL, you can just change ORDER BY like this:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(status, 2, 1, 3)
```