# Laravel Eloquent return conditionally when first condition not exists return another

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, conditional-statements

i use **Eloquent** for get Multilanguage post title.

```
    public function getTitle_en()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Meta::class, 'post_id')->where(['cat' => 'title', 'meta_name' => 'en']);
}
```

this return english title, but some times the english title not exist so i want to return title in another language .

i mean when use **getTitle_en** to get engish title (*['cat' => 'title', 'meta_name' => 'en']*) , if it's not exist return title in another language like "nl" and again if "nl" (*['cat' => 'title', 'meta_name' => 'nl']*) does not exist return in another language like "gr".

so i want Eloquent check if english title exists in my table (meta) then return it, otherwise if english title not exist , check "nl" title if it exist return **otherwise check next language**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this solution:

`$query->orderByRaw("FIELD(status, '2', '1', '3')")`

by just changing your `where()` method into accepting function. For more details, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767632/sort-laravel-collection-by-custom-order-other-than-asc-or-desc).