# Laravel filter with sortBy field

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I can order a result by field name like this:

```
->orderByRaw('FIELD(status, 'processing', 'pending', 'completed')
```

There is a way for order by field value with laravel filter like this?

```
$collection->filter(function($status) {
   ...
 })
->sortBy('FIELD(status, 'processing', 'pending', 'completed')->values()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
$filter = $filter->sortBy(function($status){
    return array_search($status->status_group, ['processing', 'pending', 'completed']);
});
```

Helped me this: [Sort Laravel Collection by custom order, other than asc or desc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767632/sort-laravel-collection-by-custom-order-other-than-asc-or-desc)