# postgresql order by field?

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I want to get the result ordered by the same order of the list, but it keeps giving errors.

```
select "Usuario"."nombre", "Usuario"."codSis" 
from "public"."Usuario"
where "codSis" in (6, 8)
order by field(codSis ,6,8)
```

this code gives mi this error

```
ERROR:  column "codsis" does not exist
LINE 4: order by field(codSis ,6,8)
                       ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "Usuario.codSis".
SQL state: 42703
Character: 112
```

but when I put this

```
select "Usuario"."nombre", "Usuario"."codSis" 
from "public"."Usuario"
where "codSis" in (6, 8)
order by field(Usuario.codSis ,6,8)
```

it gives me this error

```
ERROR:  column "Usuario.codSis" does not exist
LINE 4: order by field("Usuario.codSis" ,6,8)
                       ^
SQL state: 42703
Character: 112
```

then I tried this

```
select "Usuario"."nombre", "Usuario"."codSis" 
from "public"."Usuario"
where "codSis" in (6, 8)
order by field("Usuario"."codSis" ,6,8)
```

and it gave me this error

```
ERROR:  function field(integer, integer, integer) does not exist
LINE 4: order by field("Usuario"."codSis" ,6,8)
                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 106
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql `order by field` is mysql, postgresql doesn't have that

Comment: What was that supposed to do anyway? 6 will order before 8 without any prodding, so do you just want `order by codSis` ?

Comment: You had two issues in play here. The first was the `order by field` statement not being a Postgres one. The second is identifier quoting. If an identifier is created in upper or mixed case by being quoted("codSis" ) then it needs to be used that way from then on. For more information see: [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: What do you expect that non-existing `field()` function to do?

Comment: Can you describe how you want the data to be sorted?

Comment: I think that in the example I gave, it seemed like I just wanted it to be sorted in increasing order, I meant to be sorted in the order of any list of elements. @dratenik already solved my issue. I don't know how to close this question

Answer (score 1):

You query should be next:

```
select
  "Usuario"."nombre",
  "Usuario"."codSis" 
from "public"."Usuario"
where "codSis" in (6, 8)
order by "Usuario"."codSis" asc;
```