# rails sort by specifc order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have model named **Group** which has users_count field in it.

I have to order groups based upon dynamic preference of users_count like [3,4,2]
means show groups with 3 users_count first, than with 4 and than with 2

Right now, I am using 3 separate queries and than merge records like

```
groups = Group.where(users_count: 3)
         + Group.where(users_count: 4)
         + Group.where(users_count: 2)
```

It works but It don't make sense to use 3 separate queries.

**How can I achieve this in single query?**

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql

Comment: Did you tried?  `Group.where(user_count: [3,4,2]).group(:user_count)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 3, 4, 2 is not a sequential order there should be a custom condition to order them properly you can do it by using [the `CASE WHEN` expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-conditional.html).

```rb
order_sql = Arel.sql(
  'CASE WHEN users_count = 3 THEN 0 ' \
    'WHEN users_count = 4 THEN 1 ' \
    'ELSE 3 END'
)
Group.where(users_count: [2,3,4]).order(order_sql)
```

Which will give `0` when `users_count = 3`, `1` when `users_count = 4`, and `3` for other cases. With default ascending order you'll get the result you want.

Answer (score -2):

You can do

```
groups = Group.where(users_count: [3,4,2])
```

This will return the same `groups` as your 3 queries in a single query

Comment: The results will not neccessarily be in the same order as the values in your where clause.

Comment: its not about getting records but order is required here.