# order records based on a field value on the order of an array of ids in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

As part of sorting based on priority_id column label names, I have done the below code:

```
 products = Product.where(id: pr_ids).order("priority_id IN(?)",ordered_priority_ids)
```

The below error is showing:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...ducts"."id" IN ($2, $3) ORDER BY priority_id IN(?), 4, 2, 3...
^
):

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Please check my answer to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631962/rails-sort-by-specifc-order/67633594#67633594

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.order_by_priority_ids(ids)
  return self.where(:id => 0)  if ids.blank?
  values = []
  ids.each_with_index do |priority_id, index|
    values << "(#{priority_id}, #{index + 1})"
  end
  return self.joins("JOIN (VALUES #{values.join(",")}) as x (priority_id, ordering) ON #{table_name}.priority_id = x.priority_id").reorder('x.ordering')
end
```

And then you can use:

```
Product.where(id: pr_ids).order_by_priority_ids(ordered_priority_ids)
```