# laravel eloquent order by specific value with PostreSQL database

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, sql-order-by

I am new in PostgreSQL with Laravel. I have a query that I want to order by `status` column specific value, not alphabetical order, e.g:

```
1. pending
2. accepted
3. delivered
4. rejected
```

Before I used MySQL and it works fine. After changed database to PostgreSQL, query is not working: Here is my code:

```php
$query->orderByRaw('FIELD(status, "pending", "accepted", "delivered", "rejected") ASC')->get();
```

And error screenshot:

[image]

It shows `pending` in not table column;

Should it be different that query in laravel postgres? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309624/simulating-mysqls-order-by-field-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your `FIELD(...)` to:

```
CASE
    WHEN status='pending' THEN 1
    WHEN status='accepted' THEN 2
    WHEN status='delivered' THEN 3
    WHEN status='rejected' THEN 4
END
```